# Stuck at Flutter project run in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, android-studio, flutter, dart, android-sdk-tools

[flutter] flutter.bat doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at D:\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (5 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\vrind\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\vrind\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\vrind\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar.
    • Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
      visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\vrind\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.10.1

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.26.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.10.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
exit code 0

Comment: It looks like `flutter doctor` is telling you that it can't find parts of the Android SDK (particularly android.jar). Review your installation paths above relative to the output of this message to find your issue. Ensure you didn't accidentally delete the file in question.

Answer (score 0):

check you ANDROID_HOME path in environment variable. if not exist then create a path with name ANDROID_HOME and set the android sdk location to the path. if exist then check the location.

Answer (score 0):

I met this error, turn out I didn't add ANDROID_HOME path in the environment variable. You may want to check it again

Comment: C:\Users\vrind\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk i put this path in system variable but didn't work for me

Comment: There is another way is you remove your android studio, remove android SDK and re-install SDK through the android studio not separated installations.